# Calculate Standard Deviation in Multiplication

Tags: arithmetic, error-propagation

I have a question that asks to find the result (in sig figs) as well as the standard deviation for the following

$$(23\pm 8)\times(99\pm 11)\times(11\pm 3)\times(8\pm 4)$$

I began this question by multiplying out the numbers, which gets $200376$. This value, to 1 sig fig (since $8$ is 1 sig fig) gives $200000$. I have a bit of trouble with the standard deviation, however.

I researched and found the formula for propogation of error in multiplication to be

$$\frac{\Delta z}{z}=\left(\left(\frac{\Delta x}{x}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\Delta y}{y}\right)^2\right)^{1/2}$$

I used this, and once I calculate the right side I multiply by $200000$. This yields a number like $135308$.something. For one sig fig, I get $100000$. So my answer comes out to $200000\pm 100000$. I feel as if maybe my standard error is too big, or even I may be doing it wrong. So I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction or such. Thanks.

Comment: You result is perfectly correct.

Comment: Because the fractional error of the product is the the root sum of squares of the fractional errors of the contributing terms, the final fractional error cannot be less than the largest of the fractional error of the contributing terms. One of your contributing terms has a fractional error of 50% ($8 \pm 4 $).